# Nesting Blocks and Multiple Inheritance with Timber

Tags: inheritance, twig, block, multiple-inheritance, timber

I´ve been trying to follow [this](https://timber.github.io/docs/getting-started/theming/) And it is not working as (how I think) it should. I want to replace the content in the "headline" block or add to it, but I just get the title as established in single.twig.

base.twig:

```
<!-- Stuff -->

    {% block content %}
        Sorry, no content
    {% endblock %}

<!-- More Stuff -->
```

single.twig:

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}

<!-- Stuff-->               
{% block headline %}                    
    <h1 class="article-h1">
        <a href="{{post.link}}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </h1>
{% endblock headline %}             

<!-- More Stuff-->  

{% endblock %}
```

single-post-mypost.twig:

```
{% extends "single.twig" %}

{% block headline %}
    {{parent()}}
    <h1>Custom Header</h1>
{% endblock headline %}
```

Comment: Did you clear your cache? This code [works](https://twigfiddle.com/cjbvex) as is

Comment: Yes, I have cache disabled while the devtools are open in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it wasn't working.

In single.php Timber::render was looking for $post->ID and $post->post_type and it wasn't looking for $post->post_name.

It works now.

I've been fiddling around so much that I don't remember if it is in the original  Timber's Starter Theme but here is the code in case someone else runs into the same problem.

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = Timber::query_post();
$context['post'] = $post;
$context['sidebar'] = Timber::get_sidebar('sidebar.php');

if ( post_password_required( $post->ID ) ) {
    Timber::render( 'single-password.twig', $context );
} else {
    Timber::render( array( 'single-' . $post->post_name . '.twig', 'single-' . $post->ID . '.twig', 'single-' . $post->post_type . '.twig', 'single.twig' ), $context );
}
```